# Parse.com Send push notifications to concrete devices

Tags: parse-platform

According to this [document](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications)

I can send push notification to 'installations' using channels or query.
But how can I send notification to concrete installations/devices by their installationId?

For example I have 20 device and have their installationId and I want to send push to those 20 devices.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your circumstance you *dont* want to restrict fields by including a parameter. In other words, since you want to send a push notification to all users then you don't include any parameters. So in short, simply create an unbiased push payload with a title and description and then execute it for whatever deviceType you specify or need

Comment: You wrong understood my circumstance. I don't want to create push for entire base. Forexample I have entire base in 1000 devices, but want to push only 20 of them. How can I create push exactly to those 20 using their id? Thanks.